# How to sort in a django queries?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a table called User as custom user model in django.
I have another model called `Portfolio` and `ProjectDetail` which have a `ForeignKey` relation to my `User` model. The table structure are like this:

```
class ProjectDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectDetail, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and User model as :

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('Username'), unique=True, max_length=100, blank=False, null=False,
        help_text=_('20 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and -/_ characters, no capitals, no spaces'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('Middle Name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    about_yourself = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to find list of users with maximum number of uploaded project or find list of users with maximum number of portfolios. How can i find the sorted list of users sorted by number of `ProjecDetail` or number of `Portfolio`?

Comment: You are looking for annotation/aggregation. See the cheat-sheet [examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) for group by:

```
from django.db.models import Count

#group by portfolios count
User.objects.annotate(portfolios=Count('portfolio')).order_by('portfolios')
#group by projects count
User.objects.annotate(projects=Count('portfolio__project')).order_by('projects')
```